# Adding anonymous functions matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, anonymous-function

I have a loop

```
for i = 1: n
f = @(x) x + vec(i)
end
```

Is it posible to add up all these functions into one single anonymous function??

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that the function makes sense at all, can you try to explain what it is that you would like to sum? The first `n` elements of `vec` should be increased by `x`? Or do you want `n` separate functions, each which would increase `vec(i)` by `x`.

Comment: so at every loop the function is

x + 1,
x + 4,
x + 3,
x + 56,


What I would like is a function that is (x+1) + (x+4) + (x+3) + (x+56) +...

Comment: So you want `n` different functions that each adds a different number (pre-defined from `vec`) to `x`. And after you have your `n` function you want to do something with them all simultaneously.

Comment: Correct. Specifically I would like to add them all up to define a new anonymous function.

Comment: `f = @(x) n*x + sum(vec)` should do the trick for you. Especially since you are not storing `(x+1)`, `(x+2)`, ... in an array.

Comment: It won't work as the function is considerably more complicated. I only wrote x to make it simple to type.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can suggest is to incrementally add your functions like this:

```
n = 10;
vec = rand(1,n);    % Random data
f = @(x)x + vec(1); % Initial function
for i = 2:n
    f = @(x)x + vec(i) + f(x); % Add previous sum to next
end
x = 2;
s = f(x) % Evaluate
```

If you need to save each function separately and sum afterwards, you can create a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of function handles and use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to evaluate all of them for a particular value of `x`:

```
n = 10;
vec = rand(1,n); % Random data
f = cell(1,n);   % Pre-allocate cell
for i = 1:n
    f{i} = @(x)x + vec(i) % Save a handle to each function in cell array
end
x = 2;
s = sum(cellfun(@(c)c(x),f)) % Evaluate each function at x and sum
```

Another option would be to do this using [Symbolic Math](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html), though this may be very inefficient depending on your actual functions:

```
n = 10;
vec = rand(1,n);    % Random data
syms x;
f(x) = x+vec; % Create vector function
x = 2;
s = double(sum(f(x))); % Evaluate and convert to floating point
```

It's impossible to know what your actual problem is and if any these will work for you without a more detailed question, so you may need to alter them considerably for your particular application.